# How to calculating the inflation adjustment for a period Verbraucherpreis index

Tags: indexing, price, consumer, adjustment

How to calculate the inflation adjustment e.g. for Germany:

amount: 1.500,- EUR
index base: 2015
period: from 02.2020 to 02.2021

Answer (score 0):

**Example of calculating the inflation adjustment**

An amount of € 1,500 is secured with the VPI (2015).

The starting month / year is December 2019.
What is the amount in December 2020 (= comparison month)?

You need the values ​​of the index series 2015 for the
both months of December 2019 and December 2020.

The current tables can be found on the Internet …
for Germany: Homepage of the Federal Statistical Office
for Austria: Homepage of Statistics Austria

Required data (example AT):
Value for December 2019: **108.1**
Value for December 2020: **109.4**

Calculation:
Step 1: 109.4: 108.1 = **1.01203 (factor)**
Step 2: € 1,500 x 1.01203 = **€ 1,518**

Old amount: € 1,500
New amount:** € 1,518**

You can make use of an **API** to be consumed in your application, see also:

https://rapidapi.com/ch.walter76/api/consumer-price-index-germany-and-austria